Question about lower bound when solving Variation of Parameter IVPs
Lets say we are solving something like $y'-2xy=2$ for $y(0)=1$ when implementing variation of parameters the standard process is to identify the lower bound in the integral to be 0 so we would be doing some dummy variable integral from 0 to $x$ in this problem.
I want to know the reasoning behind why we can just identify that lower bound to 0? Is it because many differential equations are time based so negative time doesn't make much sense or maybe does it have to do with the convergence of the integral. The questions I've seen this on don't specify that $x>0$ or something too. Only condition is that at 0 the output of our result must be 1, that's it. Any insight here would be great.

The general solution to $y'-2xy=2$ is
$$
y=e^{x^2}\left(C+2\int_a^xe^{-s^2}ds\right), \tag{1}
$$
where both $C$ and $a$ are arbitrary constants. Since the initial value of $y$ is defined at $x=0$, it is convenient to set $a=0$, as this simplifies the determination of $C$:
$$
y(0)=1 \implies e^0\left(C+2\underbrace{\int_0^0e^{-s^2}ds}_{=\,0}\right)=1 
\implies 
C=1
$$
$$
\implies y(x)=e^{x^2}\left(1+2\int_0^xe^{-s^2}ds\right). \tag{2}
$$
However, that is just a matter of convenience. If we let $a\neq 0$, the value of $C$ changes, but the final result doesn't:
$$
y(0)=1 \implies e^0\left(C+2\underbrace{\int_a^0e^{-s^2}ds}_{\neq\,0}\right)=1
\implies C=1-2\int_a^0e^{-s^2}ds
$$
$$
\implies y(x)=e^{x^2}\left(1-2\int_a^0e^{-s^2}ds
+2\int_a^xe^{-s^2}ds\right)
=e^{x^2}\left(1+2\int_0^xe^{-s^2}ds\right). \tag{3}
$$

Great this helps thank you very much. That is what I figured the answer was, but just wanted to verify.
